# Eclipse RCP - Multi User Installation using Windows Environment Variables

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP application.

At startup this RCP application creates a folder for the "configuration area" [(see eclipse help)](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html) .

Currently I pass a hardcoded path to the -configuration parameter in the launcher .ini file to define the location where this folder for the "configuration area" should be located.

So far, this is working fine.

Now the requirement of a customer is, that this "configuration area" should be saved in the roaming profile of the Windows user.

The location of the roaming profile is defined by the Windows environment variable APPDATA. But this location does not corespond to the Java *user.home* directory, which points to a shared network drive in the case of my customer.

How can I implement this requirement?

As far as I found out, the only variables I can use in the launcher .ini are @user.home and @user.dir [(see Eclipse runtime options)](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html). Both seem to be useless for my scenario.

There is a [bug on the Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=102239) since 2005 that seems to address exactly my issue. But it is not resolved, and there seems not much demand in resolving the issue. So I am wondering how other people are dealing with similar scenarios?

Any help for setting up an Eclipse RCP multi-user scenario using Windows Roaming Profiles is greatly appreciated...

Comment: You could use an Installer (e.g. Nullsofts NSIS) that reads the Roaming folder and writes the folder in the ini file while installing your product...I'm afraid it's not possible to fulfill this requirement with only-eclipse-features...